# What does {} do in ES6 Object.assign function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am a little confused on some simple functionality of the Object.assign function.  Take the following:

```
const a = {'a':'1'};
const b = {'b':'2'};
const final = Object.assign(a, b) // {a:1, b:2}
```

What is the difference between that and the following:

```
const a = {'a':'1'};
const b = {'b':'2'};
const final = Object.assign( {}, a, b) // {a:1, b:2}
```

What is the purpose of the starting {} object and when is it appropriate to use it, or leave it out entirely?

Comment: uhm. is that a typo? `Object.assign{a, b}` otherwise, your question is [answered in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: `Object.assign({}, a, b) ` is side effect free, i.e it does not mutate a, but creates a new object whereas the previous approach mutates a.

Comment: @zero298 sorry fixed.

Comment: Do a `console.log(final === a)` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will mutate its first argument. So for example in your first example:

```
const a = {'a':'1'};
const b = {'b':'2'};
const final = Object.assign(a, b) // {a:1, b:2}
console.log(a); // {a:1, b:2}
```

The properties of object b are copied over to object a.

But in your second example:

```
const a = {'a':'1'};
const b = {'b':'2'};
const final = Object.assign({}, a, b) // {a:1, b:2}
console.log(a); // {a:1}
```

The `{}` will create a new object to which the properties of a and b will be copied. `Object.assign` will return its first argument.